# for_each in terraform module block returns - "for_each" argument value is unsuitable

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm, terraform-modules

I want to use count in module block but since it is not supported im trying to write for_each with a for loop but it is giving `"for_each" argument value is unsuitable` error.

I can't pass count to the inner module because it will mess my output format. can someone guide me how to properly call for_each.

main.tf

```
module "test" {
  for_each = toset([for id in range(2): {
      index = id
    }])

  source = "./am"
  name = each.value
}

output "all" {
  depends_on = [ module.test ]
  value = module.one
}
```

am/test.tf

```
variable "name" {
  type = string
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "ip" {
  name                = ..
  resource_group_name = ..
  location            = ..
  allocation_method   = ..
}

output "one" {
  description = "one_value"
  value = azurerm_public_ip.ip.ip_address
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to do this. One way is:

```
for_each = {for id in range(2): id=>id}
```

other one is:

```
for_each = toset([for id in range(2): tostring(id)])
```